# Replace string if string contains specific value for every row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, parsing

I trying to parse a csv that contains long string on different rows.
I want to replace each long string for every row that is occurs if the string contains specific value.

Why i want to replace the long string is because csv-file breaks the string to fit in the rows.

example of the csv-file is:

```
number     |      payload
1230          00023030303030303030303030303030...
1234          00033030303030303030330303030303...
1236          30303030303030004303030303030303...
1238          0005303030...
1240          (blank)
1241          (blank)
1248          0006303030...
```

The following uniq four digit values in the long string is a counter in hexadecimal form 1-100 (hex 1-63).

So i have tried to replace the value if the row contains a value with the counter, but without success.

The problem is that the four uniq value in the string may not match the counter and therefore replace it with the rough value.

```py
def stringconv(filefind)->str:
    strcount=pd.read_csv(filefind, sep='\t', usecols=[2], na_filter=False, names=col_name)
    for i in range(256):
        counter = "{:02x}".format(i)
        hxstr = strcount["payload"].str.match("00" + str(counter))
        hexstring = strcount[strcount["payload"].str.match("00" + str(counter))]
        print(hexstring)
        j = ("00" + str(counter))
        for x in hxstr:
            if x == True:
                strcount.replace(x,j, inplace=True)
```

The existing file as shown above should look more like:

```
number     |     payload
1230             0002
1234             0003
1236             0004
1238             0005
1240             (blank)
1241             (blank)
1248             0006
...              ...
```